# MySql Query Order BY datetime and Group By Id issue

Tags: mysql

Having issue with this query

there is 3 rows in comments table with different date-times, I want customer list with last comment created_date / updated_date.
 but didn't getting last commented customer with group by customer

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT MAX(comments.`date_updated`), customer.id AS vid, comments.`date_updated` AS dts, comments.`id` AS comments_id, comments.* FROM customer
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.`customer_id` = customer.`id`
 WHERE customer.`id` IN ('')
) AS v
GROUP BY v.`vid` LIMIT 0,50
```

Answer (score 1):

You use a self join to comments table and filter row for each customer with latest `date_updated`

```
SELECT c.id AS vid, co.`date_updated` AS dts, co.`id` AS comments_id, co.*
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN comments co ON co.`customer_id` = c.`id`
LEFT JOIN comments co1 ON co.`customer_id` = co1.`customer_id` AND co.date_updated < co1.date_updated
WHERE co1.customer_id IS NULL  AND c.`id` IN ('')
```

Or with inner join

```
SELECT c.id AS vid, co.`date_updated` AS dts, co.`id` AS comments_id, co.*
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN comments co ON co.`customer_id` = c.`id`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, MAX(date_updated) date_updated
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY customer_id
) co1 ON co.customer_id = co1.customer_id AND co.date_updated =  co1.date_updated
WHERE c.`id` IN ('')
```

Comment: Inner join is fine but there is large number of rows in customer & comments so its 5.78 sec taking execution time .

Comment: @SurendraSuthar Do check your indexes also its good to have a composite index on customer_id,date_updated

Comment: @SurendraSuthar i guess you need to apply limit on your data set like in your example  `LIMIT 0,50` clause

Comment: Yes bro these all things i am using

Comment: @SurendraSuthar Last try how about you move limit clause in inner query, also do run `explain` plan for your query and see what taking up the time

Answer (score 0):

You forgot order by clause

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT MAX(comments.`date_updated`), customer.id AS vid, comments.`date_updated` AS dts, comments.`id` AS comments_id, comments.* FROM customer
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.`customer_id` = customer.`id`
 WHERE customer.`id` IN ('')
) AS v
GROUP BY v.`vid` LIMIT 0,50
ORDER BY created_date desc;
```

Comment: See there is already using MAX(comments.`date_updated`) & i have tried these all things so this is wrong.